# Chrome redraw not happening correctly after jquery fadeout() - element retains height of hidden element in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, fadeout

I am fading an element on mousehover/mouseleave

```
  function hoverIn() {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('megadropdown-expanded');
    var activeitem = $(this).data("mlid");
    $('.paddle-mega-dropdown[data-mlid=' + activeitem + ']').fadeIn("fast");
  }
  function hoverOut(e) {
    var activeitem = $(this).data("mlid");
    var targetElement = e.relatedTarget;
    if ($(targetElement).closest('[data-mlid=' + activeitem + ']').length == 0) {
      $('.paddle-mega-dropdown[data-mlid=' + activeitem + ']').fadeOut("fast").css("position", "absolute");
      $('.menu-item[data-mlid=' +activeitem + ']').find('a').removeClass('megadropdown-expanded');
    }
  }
```

everything worked fine, until I removed `position: absolute` from the element. (I keep it at the normal flow of the document under small screens)

```
.paddle-mega-dropdown {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 13px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.36);
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Now, on Google Chome, when I `hoverOut()`, the element keeps it's space on the layout.. and the element after it does not jump back in place. (this works ok for Firefox)

If I change any layout value on my Dev tools, a reflow is triggered and things look normal again.

I noticed that if I don't use the fadeOut but the slideDown/slideUp the problem is solved, but this is not the desired effect I need.

It seems like setting the element to `display: none` with fadeOut(), behaves more like `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: I just realized if I chain a height animation as well, the problem goes away, but I'm going to wait to see if there's a cleaner fix. Is this some Chrome Bug?

Comment: Adding a live demo (like in http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/ or any other site) would be helpful.

Comment: @DenilsonSá maybe maybe not.. the html and the css code around this is quite much and I cannot isolate the code responsible for the problem. In fact I was able to find a workaround - I animate the height and then I hide the element. I'm sure it's a question of forcing a redraw and the position of the element in the HTML but I can't find any clean way to do this

Comment: Try to inspect the html behavior using any DOM Explorer (pressing F12 in any browser for developer tools). See if the `fadeOut()` is not leaving any trash behind orif it have diferente behavier from one browser to another. If you realize any suspect, please notify.

Comment: Firefox and IE work. Webkit doesn't.

Comment: When you said you removed `position: absolute` did you mean from the CSS you posted without it, or from the javascript you posted with it ?

Comment: @lapin This is a classic dropdown where when you hover over it it expands, absolutely positioned above everything else. What I did is I removed position: absolute in order for it to "push" the rest of the content. I'll update my question with the HTML

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Since you mentioned that you have animated the height and then hidden the element, can provide me some source or leads on how can we achieve that?

Comment: Really sorry, this is a 2+ yr old question and I dont have the resources necessary to reproduce it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the problem on both `Firefox 33` and `Chrome 38`, and after I removed the `position: absolute` from the JS (as you mentionned you wanted the element to flow with everything), it just works well.

You said you were using the `mousehover` event, but this doesn't exist so you probably meant the `mouseover` jquery event. You may check in your code if there's no syntaxic confusion around that point.

Here's the simplified javascript I used based on your code and explanations :

```
function hoverIn() {
    $('.paddle-mega-dropdown').fadeIn("fast");
}
function hoverOut(e) {
    $('.paddle-mega-dropdown').fadeOut("fast");
}
$('#hover-this').mouseover(hoverIn);
$('#hover-this').mouseleave(hoverOut);
```

I also created a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ngnjddbw/1/) so you can check that the above works in Firefox as well as in Chrome.

Comment: THanks for taking the time to make the fiddle! I will fork it and make the HTML closer to the real usecase I have might that will reproduce it... (FYI there is more HTML between the hover element and the dropdown element..)

Answer (score 0):

I would try using fadeToggle instead of the fadein/fadeout paradigm you have setup. That way the DOM element can easily be created and destroyed with one call instead of two.

```
$( "megadropdown-expanded" ).hover(function() {
  $('.paddle-mega-dropdown[data-mlid=' + activeitem + ']').fadeToggle("fast", "linear" );
});
```

But without an example here, I don't know if I can be of much more help than this.